# How can I display LinkedIn company updates from website?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-plugins

For one of my projects, we would like to display the latest LinkedIn company updates on the intranet site.

We have tried the following solutions:

- Use LinkedIn Company Insider plugin, but it seems to display only Company Employees
- Use LinkedIn Company Profile plugin, but it displays only information on the company
- Use LinkedIn REST API, but impersonation is forbidden by LinkedIn Guideline.

We could grant admin access for all employees, but it would be a bad solution because they could modify the company page on LinkedIn.

Have you ever displayed LinkedIn Company updates on the website? And which solution have you used?

Answer (score 0):

you can use linkedIn API to get company update using this api : https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?format=json

Source: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates

Comment: Yes, we could use rest api but all employees need to be admin of company  page. I think that is a bad solution.